# History.replaceState() tira error Uncaught DOMException

Tags: javascript, html5

En el .js del index de mi proyecto uso un replaceState() antes de pasar a la siguiente página con un href. El problema es que a veces funciona y a veces no... no comprendo la verdad. El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.history.replaceState(
        'https://mi-dominio.com/',
        'Just foward',
        'https://mi-dominio.com/The%20Center/Between%20Walls.html'
      );
      window.location.href = '../The Center/Between Walls.html';
    }, 500);
```

Alguien podría explicarme cuál es el problema. Muchas gracias.

En consola dice:
behavior.js:71 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://mi-dominio.com/The%20Center/Between%20Walls.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://mi-dominio.com' and URL 'http://mi-dominio.com/'.
at http://mi-dominio.com/Introduction/behavior.js:71:26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun el error la URL que se espera reeplazar es `https://mi-dominio.com` (sin el ultimo `/`). Si no planeas utilizar el primer parametro puedes simplemente enviar un objeto vacio. De otro modo la URL a reemplazar debe ser la misma que se encuentra en el estado de historia actual.

```
      window.history.replaceState(
        {},
        'Just forward',
        'https://mi-dominio.com/The%20Center/Between%20Walls.html'
      );
```

Por otra parte replaceState() esta diseñada para reemplazar la URL actual en la barra de direcciones sin necesidad de actualizar la pagina en si, por lo que cambiar `document.location.href` producira una actualizacion de la pagina real de todas maneras.

Otra forma mas directa de lograr cambiar la url actual, actualizando la pagina es usando `document.location.replace(newUrl);

```
document.location.replace('https://mi-dominio.com/The%20Center/Between%20Walls.html');
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, gracias. Ahora la testeo. Por otro lado, sí, quiero que se cargue el documento ese Between Walls.html pero sin que aparezca en el historial que se pasó por la primera página. Luego vuelvo a hacer lo mismo. El efecto es el de un camino de ida. Con document.location.replace estaría logrando lo mismo?

Comment: Ahí implemente lo del objeto vacío y me tira el mismo error...

Comment: Revisa el contenido completo del mensaje de error, la parte final del mensaje puede ser diferente y debe estar indicando otro error. Usar document.location.replace quitara de la historia la pagina actual y solo dejara la ultima cargada, que es el mismo efecto que deseas segun entiendo

Comment: Cuando reemplazas la URL se carga una nueva pagina totalmente, asi que el 'lag' que ves es el normal de cargar una pagina nueva. SI quieres una transicion mas suave, puedes considerar reemplazar el contenido con una carga por Ajax a la nueva pagina e incrustar el contenido, sin tener que recargar la pagina (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: F.Igor, me harías el grandísimo favor de editar tu respuesta para que no quede expuesta la url de mi página. Fue una insensatez de mi parte publicar la pregunta con la url verdadera. Acabo de editar mi pregunta cambiando la url por "mi-dominio.com". Muchas gracias y disculpa las molestias

Comment: @Sancaf Editado